Persist current state or retrieve it from history in a SQL database?
Consider a SQL database with 2 tables:

Employee containing employees' data (name, date of birth etc.)
StatusHistory tracking every change of employees status, with date and time of the change

I want to retrieve the information of an employee and to update it occasionnally. I want to keep the history of status changes.
Approaches to manage an employee's status information:

Storing the current status in Employee, while status changes are traced in StatusHistory. We update Employee status every time we add a new entry in StatusHistory.

Not storing current status. Every time we retrieve employee information we compute status from StatusHistory.

A hybrid between 1 and 2. Foreign key Employee points to the last StateHistory entry of the employee.


2 is more computing-heavy, especially if the history table is really big, but it avoids duplicating status information in two tables (minimizing the risk of inconsistency).
1 is probably better if I have many times more reading than writing of status, but we need to update both tables (either in application code or via a trigger) on any modification.
What are other ways?
Which is better, considering:

ease of use, simplicity
robustness, error tolerance (in case of application crash or database failure)
performance


This is both opinion and scenario based. As you say, history size and read/write balance are factors. History query frequency is another factor.
My own approach is usually to have just the Employee table, and the StatusHistory might (or might not) be known to the application, fed through a trigger (any value change to Employee will add an entry to StatusHistory).

Both 2 and 3 seem pretty bad to me, making this a opinion-based question!

Simplicity for person 1 is complication for person 2, performance impossible to tell because you don't mention how it will be used etc. All the stuff is pretty much "depends on", which i'm sure you know already

@siggemannen As I mentionned previously in a deleted comment (not by me, maybe you have the right to delete other people's comment...?), a question is opinion based when it can be answered only by "I prefer this over this" or "I don't like". Here the critera are clearly given. You could have explain why "2 and 3 seems pretty bad", but you didn't. I'm quite familiar with SO's daily toxicity, but it takes a conscious effort to not be part of it. An effort many people just don't want to make, apparently.

I can't delete anything, but maybe someone else did. A question can only be answered by opinion when there's no "absolute" way of doing things, which is what you're asking for here. If you would add more details, there might be a wiggle room, but you didn't. Let's say for example, method 1. It has no downsides except you need to make two inserts, so there's duplicated data. Method 2 avoids that, but every read of status requires complicated join. Method 3 is more complex to implement (needs some extra IDs, requires update) but it keeps the duplicate to a minimum and fetching is a simple join

But you didn't state the pattern of your application, or what complicated means for you. For example, maybe you don't have access to triggers, or maybe you need to have everything in one shot, or maybe you write this status 99.99% of times, and read it never. Then it would be perhaps possible to suggest something concrete. In my opinion, method 1 is clearly the best, because it worked for the systems i used and patterns of reading/writing reasonable in those systems, but i'm not you, so this becomes my opinion

CQRS (which followed from Greg Young's understanding of "event sourcing") observes that read patterns and update patterns are different, and you probably want to have appropriate data access patterns for each.
Pat Helland's classic Data on the Outside versus Data on the Inside includes a lot of overlapping ideas, in particular paying attention to locks

The fact that [the data] is unlocked means that the data is
no longer in the “now”.

So if you were to follow these ideas, you would probably end up with a data model with a status history and a status cache; anybody that's just interested in reading a recent copy of the status gets it out of the cache, being mindful of the fact that the information there could already be out of date.  Processes interested in updating the employee status work with the history, making sure they have a lock so that no edits are lost and necessary invariants are maintained.
Off to the side, somewhere, we have a process responsible for updating the status cache by reading an (unlocked) copy of the status history and upserting the correct replacement.
Warning: cache invalidation is one of Phil Karlton's two hard problems.
(It might also be worth looking into how data warehouse designers would model your information; you might look for Ralph Kimball's writings, then pivot from there to a more modern approach.)

"Occasionally" is sort of hard to work with.
If you plan on working with the History-table (ie. Find employees that switched from state 3 to 5 the past year), I'd go with option 2. And maybe, if it turns out that querying for current state is too expensive, apply option 3.
But if an employee on average has very few state-changes, and is only ever used for display purposes, then I would consider going for option 1 - but in stead of a separate table for history, just use a json-doc in a varchar-field in the employee table. Worst case, you can move the history to a separate table later - and otherwise you get all the data in one table.
